# .xsession-errors is huge after suspending

Tags: suspend, disk-usage

Earlier today I left my laptop suspended and when I came back (a few hours later), I logged in and all my disk space had been used up. I took a look at Disk Usage Analyser and it said all of the space was being used in my home folder. However, nothing was actually that big. What's hogging all my disk space?

Comment: Turns out it was a backup .xsession-errors file (.xsession-errors.old). I deleted it and got all the disk space back. However, the real one (.xsession-errors) is rapidly increasing in size as well. It looks like there's a really big problem in x.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever program is emitting so much debug info it's filling your disk has a bug. I recommend you either file a bug about it, with some sample lines, or post a sample here.